# Is there a command to find the Unix flavor?

Tags: unix, command

I am facing problem to find the [Unix flavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Current_official_derivatives). Is there a command so I can check the Unix flavour?

I have tried the below commands, but that's not working as expected.

```
$  lsb_release -irc
ksh: lsb_release:  not found

$  uname -a
SunOS servername 5.10 Generic_150400-27 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V890

$ cat /proc/version
cat: cannot open /proc/version
```

The flavor should be like *[Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29)*, *[HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX)*, *teport*, or [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX).

Comment: LSB stands for [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) and as the name implies is Linux-specific. As for the `uname` output and Solaris, SunOS 5 is Solaris, so you get your answer there. Oh, and the [procfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) filesystem is very specific to each platform that have it, there's really no standard for it. Lastly a note about terminology, when one normally mentions "UNIX flavor" one usually means e.g. SYSV or BSD.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg i got you SunOS 5 mean its Solaris

Comment: how about: uname -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname

Answer (score 4):

`uname -a && cat /etc/*release`

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /proc/version
```

should give you the flavour.

You can check what's in your proc by doing `ls /proc`